# Simple null reference bug thats killing me (Java)

Tags: java, eclipse, subclass, nullreferenceexception, superclass

Alright so I am messing around with some code in java and I am getting a wierd error. I have my class Chaos which has a Window variable FSW, public as well. Now I have another class called Look. Chaos creates a Look and then runs the Look.Init() method. That init method runs the looks run method which tries to reference the FSW variable of its parent Chaos.

The problem is that no matter how I got about it whenever I reference -any- variable from Chaos from within Look the variable is null =/. I can call Chaos methods from the subclass Look but I cant reference variables.

Here is a link to a text hosting site, if anyone thinks it would be necessary for me to export and upload the package I guess I will but I feel like this might be just something I am not seeing that is obvious.

http://www.text-upload.com/read.php?t=1790

Comment: I suggest to cut down your code as much as possible until you end up with the smallest possible executable sample which reproduces exactly your problem and just post it in your question. There's way too much noise in the linked code to quickly spot the cause of the problem.

Comment: And adding to what BalusC said: Here on SO, the idea is that it will stand *alone* as a question and answer system and archive. The code should be actually *in* the question, not linked in an external resource that can go away / move / etc. (Ugh, and the code at the link is completely unformatted.)

Comment: T.J.: The code at the link is formatted if you click on the TXT or RTF icons. I suspect that the text-upload.com site has no way to show the code with the proper `<pre>` tags.

Comment: Posting a Question about code you've pasted somewhere else is a bad idea.  1) Some people (like me) are hesitant to visit random other sites. 2) The chances are that the code won't be there in a few days, meaning that the context of the Question and Answers will be lost ... making them useless for other folks.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is your not actually referencing a variable from within Chaos, your referencing a variable from within Look.

i.e. you create a new Look() object with it's own instance of FSW which by default is initalised to null, this is never set inside Look

If you want to reference the variable in Chaos I suggest you pass the Chaos object into the Look's constructor.

So in look you would put a new field chaos, and add a constructor like so

```
public Look(Chaos chaos){
   this.chaos = chaos
}
```

Inside Chaos when creating Look you would then do

```
new Look(this)
```

Inside look you could then reference chaos.FSW